# Need Help with Modelling

Tags: modeling

I am still a Beginner to modelling, and I am trying to model the design shown above, but i cant wrap my head around it on how to make this,Any help is appreciated.[image]

Comment: Is "this" the entire box, or the pattern of the front panel, or something else?  If it's the pattern, [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/251643/42221) works.  If it's the entire object, start by working with basic shapes -- in this case a lot of cubes -- and modifying them to fit the part.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a plane, cut some edges, extrude:

[image]

Move down some vertices, then forward:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand now.